# Store information in branch (metadata) about which point it diverged from "parent" branch

Tags: git, git-checkout

Say I have this:

```
latest_commit=`git rev-parse HEAD`
git checkout -b "foo_$latest_commit"
git reset --soft "origin/dev"
```

what I am doing is keeping track of where the 2nd branch diverged from the first. But instead of putting the commit id in the name of the 2nd branch, is there a way to store metadata somewhere in the 2nd branch so I don't have to put a long commit id in the name of the branch?

Ultimately, what am I trying to do? I am going to merge foo_$latest_commit into the the integration branch after squashing the commits by using `git reset --soft`. Later down the road, I want to be able to safely delete both the first and the second branch. I can safely delete the first branch if the tip of the first branch matches the commit id in the name of the second branch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ... is there a way to store metadata somewhere in the 2nd branch ...

Not directly, no.

Remember that each branch *name* is merely a (moveable) pointer to a commit, with the special property that if you use `git checkout` to get "on" the branch, `git commit` *automatically* moves the pointer.  Various other commands are willing to move it in various fashions: e.g., `git merge --ff-only` will move the current branch name in a fast-forward manner, while `git reset` will move it arbitrarily.

So: where *can* you store metadata?  This is a bit tricky.

Git consists of two primary databases: the repository itself is a key-value store with hash IDs as keys and repository objects (blobs, trees, commits, and annotated-tags) as values.  Meanwhile the references—branch names in `refs/heads/*`, tag names in `refs/tags/*`, the stash in `refs/stash`, and so on—are a key-value store with a few slightly weird constraints on the keys (see `git check-ref-format` for most of them) whose values are hash IDs.

Since your goal is (I think) to associate a *branch name* with two *different* hash IDs, one obvious approach is to invent your own namespace within `refs`.  Let's say we choose, for instance, `refs/bases/`.  For a branch whose name is B (full name `refs/heads/B` for instance), you merely need to create a `refs/bases/B`.  The only thing you can store in `refs/bases/B` is a hash ID, but that's precisely what you want to store, so you are done.

Should you wish to store more than, or something other than, a simple hash ID—e.g., if you want to store another *name*—you'll need some sort of data object.  Your choices are any of the four object types, but two of them are strongly constrained: a tree or a commit must be formatted correctly.  One of them is weakly constrained: an *annotated tag object* must contain the hash ID of another object—the target of the annotated tag—and can then contain arbitrary text.  The last one, *blob*, is unconstrained as it may contain any arbitrary text.

To create an annotated tag object, use `git mktag`.  See its documentation for the required tag format.

To create a blob, use `git hash-object -w`, probably with `--stdin`; see its documentation.

Both output a hash ID, which you can then set as the hash ID to be stored under `refs/bases/B` or `refs/xyz-meta/B` or whatever name-space you choose.

#### One last note

For most Git usage, the way to work is not to store a base branch name, nor a base commit hash ID.  Instead, use *set subtraction* to ask for *reachable* commits, in the form:

- All commits reachable from name *T* (for tip); but
- Excluding all commits reachable from name *S* (for stop).

This is precisely what `git rebase` does with the argument you pass it, for instance: when you run `git checkout feature; git rebase develop`, Git enumerates all the commits *reachable from* `feature`, *minus* all the commits reachable from `develop`.  This is so common in Git that it has a `git rev-list` syntax: `develop..feature` means `feature ^develop` which means "commits reachable from `feature`, excluding commits reachable from `develop`".

(What you can get with your metadata trick is to automatically remember the appropriate name—but it turns out that in practice, most people mostly don't seem to need this.  For your particular usage, it may well be a good thing, though.  I put this section in because I'm sure in the future, other people will find your question and this answer and think it's a clever way to remember a "base branch" for each derived branch.  Which it is, but that's not such a clever thing to do.)

Comment: thanks, right now I am using `git config --local branch.x` to store metadata in the local repo, is there a better way than that? The purpose is so the metadata is not branch specific. The metadata needs to be the same, no matter what branch I am on.

Comment: The issue with using the configuration is that it's kind of fragile (limited amount of data, not preservable across clone, etc). But if that works for you, it's OK too.

Comment: yeah many things we could store we can recalculate quickly - basically I diverge one branch from another and I want to store the point at which they diverged. But if that info can be retrieved if both branches still exist in the future, then I don't really need to store/persist that info.